# Is it safe to pass a struct with "ref this" to native code

Tags: c#, pinvoke

I am currently integrating the Steamworks SDK into my game and have a couple of methods which require to pass a struct as a pointer, for example:

```c
// Public interface method declared by the library
S_API bool SteamAPI_SteamNetworkingIPAddr_IsLocalHost( SteamNetworkingIPAddr* self );
```

```cs
// C# implementation

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit, Size = 18, Pack = 1)]
public struct SteamNetworkingIPAddr {

    // My current usage of "ref this"
    public bool IsLocalhost => NativeMethods.SteamAPI_SteamNetworkingIPAddr_IsLocalHost(ref this);

    // How another library solves it
    public bool IsLocalhost {
        get {
            SteamNetworkingIPAddr copy = this;
            NativeMethods.SteamAPI_SteamNetworkingIPAddr_IsLocalHost(ref self);
        }
    }


    private static class NativeMethods {
        [DllImport(SteamAPI.LIBRARY_NAME, EntryPoint = "SteamAPI_SteamNetworkingIPAddr_IsLocalHost", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        internal static extern bool SteamAPI_SteamNetworkingIPAddr_IsLocalHost(ref SteamNetworkingIPAddr self);
    }
}
```

I am a bit concerned about passing `this` with `ref` to the native method because I've seen other implementations which create a copy of the struct before passing it but I could not find something which officially says that it's either safe or unsafe to do so.

So, my question is - should I make a copy or keep my solution?

Comment: Copying makes sense if the function might modify the structure when this is not desired, but `IsLocalhost` won't (it's explicitly marked `const` in the C++ headers), so passing the reference directly should be safe.

Comment: ref will pass a pointer to the structure. What's the problem with that? Many p/invoke code do this.

Comment: `this` for a value type is by definition a `ref` managed pointer, so this should work. Note that the *caller* of your code may be doing a defensive copy, so *they* might not see changes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a instance method or property of a `struct`, the implicit `this` parameter is a `ref` managed reference. So any changes to the struct *do* mutate (change) the struct passed in.

Therefore, when you call the native function, you are passing an actual reference to your own struct. So it is possible for *your* caller to see these changes, *if* they have passed in a reference to their own struct. But depending on how your caller makes this call, there may be a defensive copy anyway.

For example:

```
var isLocal = SomeClass.IPAddrProperty.IsLocalhost
```

this will create a copy of the struct, and any changes will disappear.

Whereas this:

```
var ipAddr = SomeClass.IPAddrProperty;
var isLocal = ipAddr.IsLocalhost;
SomeClass.IPAddrProperty = ipAddr;
```

means that the results are copied back.